# AngularJS (-material) ng-disabled boolean trouble

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a problem,

I have a `<md-datepicker>` where you can select a date.

I have a select list using

`<md-checkbox ng-disabled="!formName.something.stop || !formName.something.start" 
ng-init="formName.something.action=false"> Action <md-checkbox>`

When you select a date the `<md-checkbox>` comes available. So I can select it. Now here comes the problem!

(on my page)

I select a date, I select the `<md-checkbox>`, then I remove the date on the `<md-datepicker>`. And press the 'send' button, the boolean still comes true.

```
Object {start: undefined, stop: undefined, action: true, item: false, broadcast: false…}
```

Does someone know a way when the `<md-checkbox>` is disabled I get a false back no matter if it is selected yes or no. Using something from angular(-material). Or is the best way just to use java-script?

If something is not clear what I mean, just ask :)

Thanks for already reading this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have logic in place to determine when to enable/disable the checkbox, so why not re-use that logic when sending the form.

Eg, in your controller, you could have something like this:

```
$scope.checkBoxDisabled = checkboxIsDisabled();

function checkboxIsDisabled () {
    return !formName.something.stop || !formName.something.start;
}

//Then, on form submit, just check again:
var formSubmitCheckDisabled = checkboxIsDisabled():
```

And in your view, just reference the variable you created:

```
<md-checkbox ng-disabled="checkBoxDisabled" ng-init="formName.something.action=false"> Action <md-checkbox>
```